# How to wrap and hide the Hibernate Session

Tags: java, hibernate, session, architecture, dao

Is there a way to **wrap** ***Hibernate's Session*** with my own class? My purpose is to **limit** Hibernate within **data management layer**. My **business layer** will do **session management** for opening a new session and close a finished session. But I hope there is **no Hibernate import** exist in the business layer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an intermediate DAO layer to hide the Hibernate Session details from your business logic.

You can use [Spring Transaction support](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) for session management and [Spring Data](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/) for the simplest possible DAO layer implementation.

There's no need to reinvent the wheel.